# Adding String obj into a list within a list

Tags: java, object, methods

I keep getting an "identifier expected" when trying to use this statement. 
Does anyone have an idea why? .get is a method call of arrayList and im just getting an int index and I'm adding a string to that a list inside my arrayList

```
 ArrayList Obj.get.(index).add(Str);
```

Comment: Why do you have the word "ArrayList" at the front?

Comment: Just to show that is my type of object

Comment: I'm trying to get the index of my inner list inside my array list and add my string to the correct inner list because I have multiple of them

Comment: can you elaborate more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors.

- First of all, that line is not declaring a variable, and therefore you don't specify the type (`ArrayList`).
- Assuming your variable is called `Obj`, I would recommend you to call it something meaningful and name variables starting with lower-case letters (same deal with `Str`).
- Do not add a dot (`.`) after the method name (`get(index)`).

After that, your line should look like this:

```
list.get(index).add(str);
```

---

To give you a better understanding, you can split that line of code in multiple lines:

```
List<String> subList = mainList.get(index);
subList.add(str);
```

Comment: It tells me I can not add string to my list(array list) of lists(linkedlists)

Comment: Declare em as List and assign em ArrayList and LinkedList, etc

Comment: Could clarify what you mean? I don't quite understand.